# How to inject static properties in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multilingual

I'm trying to creating a utility class with some static methods and properties, the problem is that these properties should be loaded from the messages.properties files, for multilingual porpouse.

I think I should use the MessageSourceAware but how to keep the methods static? I'm getting quite lost..

And more, how I can get the Locale? We're using a SessionLocaleResolver but I think that in the jsp is automatically loaded. How can I get it in a class?

[Thanks, I'm quite new in Spring]

---

I'll try to explain it a little better.

I've a class defined like

```
public MyClass {
    protected static final MY_PROP = "this is a static property";

    protected static String getMyProp() {
        return MY_PROP;
    }
}
```

and I would like to inject the MY_PROP from my messages.properties file, depending on the Locale, something like

```
public MyClass {
    protected static final MY_PROP = messageSource.getMessage("my.prop", locale);

    protected static String getMyProp() {
        return MY_PROP;
    }
}
```

Is this possible soomehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I've implemented the MessageSourceAware, removed the static references and injected my class.

So something like:

```
public MyClass implements MessageSourceAware {
    // this is automatically injected by Spring
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }
    // ###################

    protected String getMyProp(Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("my.prop", null, locale);
    }
}
```

and in my Rest service the Locale is automatically injected by Spring, thanks to the RequestMapping. I've injected also the entire class to avoid the static methods.

```
@Controller
public class Rest {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/test", headers="Accept=application/json")
    public String myMethod(Locale locale) {
        return myClass.getMyProp(locale);
    }
}
```

and this is working. : )

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered by trying to use [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html)

**OR** you can get some help by injectng a static property for your applicationContext.xml like this:-

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="de.inweb.blog.BadDesign.setTheProperty"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="theProperty"/>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited the question to make it more clear. Could you help me on how use the MethodInvokingFactoryBean to get that result? The doc doesn't seem so clear to me..